# Resilience to the neurotoxins of Indian King Cobra

Tags: physiology, herpetology

I read on Wikipedia about this:

[King Cobra - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_cobra#Venom)

In Thailand, a concoction of alcohol and the ground root of turmeric is ingested, which has been clinically shown to create a strong resilience against the venom of the king cobra, and other snakes with neurotoxic venom.

Though, I have been in the village parts of India where King Cobra is frequently encountered, I have never heard of this knowledge.

Can somebody please explain the scientific basis of this statement and possible reasons for this?

[PS]: Can somebody also please create a tag for "Snakes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, turmerin, the compound in turmeric has been medically proven to help neutralize venom from King Cobras in snakes ([reference1](http://jcpronline.com/final/098457ck.pdf), [reference2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1440627)). It has also been used in ayurveda for snake bite treatment ([reference](http://www.ayurvedacollege.com/articles/students/turmeric)) The alcohol I guess is just used to help ingest the turmeric and act as a pain reliever, though it strangely seems counter-productive since most snakebite help guides advice against the consumption of alcohol after getting bitten ([reference1](http://www.auroville.org/contents/1675), [reference2](http://arachnophiliac.info/burrow/snakebite_advice.htm)) due to its blood thinning properties.

Having said that, I guess personally, I would go for anti-venom rather than ingest turmeric. As a quick remedy until you get the anti-venom you should be able to depend on turmeric.

Comment: I think the alcohol is used to extract the turmerin from the roots.

Comment: @Chris Yes it is one way of doing so apparently.

Comment: Turmerin is water soluble. Perhaps they extract curcumin with alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

As The Last Word said turmeric is a suggested medicine for cobra bites in India,also Bromelain found in Pineapple and Papain in Papaya fruit are also suggested medicines by folks. Although they are unaware of these chemicals they do use these fruits for venom treatment.
Also oral administration of garlic is said as a prophylactic tool against cobra venom.
Azadirachta indica(Neem) is also a prescribed medicine for Indian Cobra bites.

http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0CE8QFjAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F51064057_Herbs_and_herbal_constituents_active_against_snake_bite%2Flinks%2F0912f50a48bd135b2c000000&ei=AlF0VImNFoaNuASv8YCICw&usg=AFQjCNE9BJ_rGjd3eG2TH-rSJh4-bIaq6w&sig2=1iP7DTk7Z34YZ4vWiQnvbg&bvm=bv.80185997,d.c2E&cad=rja

> Cipadessa baccifera leaves have powerful anti venom properties, especially for the treatment of cobra poison.
>   http://indiabiodiversity.org/species/show/31204

Aristolochia taxa have also been used as reptile repellents. Aristolochia  serpentaria (Virginia snakeroot) is thus named because the root was used to treat snakebite, as "so offensive to these reptiles, that they not only avoid the places where it grows, but even flee from the traveler who carries a piece of it in his hand".

I couldn't find if there is any remedy for snake bites exist in Thailand as you said but i found this,

> A hospital in Thailand hooked up with Mahasarakham University and brewed up a remedy. It’s a mix of betel nut, lime juice and the root of Trigonstemon reidiodes. "
>   https://hughpaxton.wordpress.com/tag/kap-choeng-hospital-develops-herbal-cure-for-cobra-snake-bite/

Without references I would suggest a traditional snake bite remedy used in my place called "Vishakallu"[Venom Stone] with ingredients

Ocimum sanctum (Tulsi leaves),
Anisomeles malabarica(Perumthumba),
Sandal wood

these medicines are treated with a stone and this stone is used for healing and it is then placed in cow milk and stored in cow dung ash and can be reused 15+ times.

Answer (score 0):

what it means is that a warm clear extract of turmeric powder given as oral drink and  washing of the snake bite wound will save the person from death till the antibody injection is given. the above is due to stoppage of a toxic enzyme called PLA2 which universally present in all snake venoms
if one thinks that it is like an ad it  shows the in ability to understand and i feel such irresponsible statements are best avoided 
 leela srinivas

Comment: Welcome to Bio and thanks for the great answer. Do you happen to have a reference at hand?

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the query, I would have search would have shown that, we are the pioneers to first use Turmeric against snake venom.  Be it, Cobra, Krait or Viper. It is the universal truth that, all the snake venom is 90% protein and out of that, 60% is the lethal inflammatory toxic enzyme called Phospholipase A2 (PLA2).  PLA2 is an enzyme that breaks down the cellular plasma membrane containing phospholipid and allows the entry of toxic enzyme.  The toxic enzyme let loose a cascade of events that goes through cyclo-oxygenase and lipoxygenase pathway with release of arachidonic acid - 20 carbon fatty acid which forms the precursor of pain causing inflammatory by-products.  Since, Turmeric can destroy the activity of phospholipase A2,the inflammation and accompanying inflammation reduced considerably and the life of the patient extended by two to three hours giving time for the anti-venom antibody treatment. The attractive feature of the above "On the spot" treatment by Turmeric is that, the snake can be any species because PLA2 is the key toxic enzyme in all the venoms. The way to administer Turmeric on the field is to take two to three fist full of Turmeric powder and dissolve it in warm water, then it is filtered through a clean cloth and the clear extract without any residue about a glass is given to drink by the patient when it is warm.  The rest of the water is used to continuously washed the bitten spot so that, the local inflammation is subsidized. You may refer the to the following publications where it is shown that Turmerin, a water soluble antioxidant protein from Turmeric binds to PLA2 distal to the active site and changes the conformation of Phospholipase A2 in such a way that, it is no more hypertoxic.  Thus extending the life of the patient and reducing pain and inflammation.

Reference:
[New biological activity against phospholipase A2 by Turmerin, a protein from Curcuma longa L.](http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/bchm.2008.389.issue-3/bc.2008.024/bc.2008.024.xml;jsessionid=BA4284943310CD38D2BD7E782A7CF511)

Comment: As of current, it's unclear what you are trying to convey with this answer. Could you clean up this post?

Comment: It reads more like an advertisement to me. I vote for deletion.